# How do I refer to a control in a WPF nested ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, progress-bar, controls

My XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvAlbums" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/downloads/Album}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="spAlbum">
                    <!-- Displays first level attributes -->
                    <TextBlock x:Name="AlbumName" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="AlbumArtist" Text="{Binding XPath=@Artist}"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="lvTracks" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="spTrack">
                                    <!-- Displays the second level attributes -->
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="trackName" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
                                    <ProgressBar x:Name="pb1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="5px" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

It populates just fine from an xml file. I have an album and listed underneath are the tracks and a progress bar for each track.

I am now looping though the XML to download each track. How do I refer to the progressbar?

(ProgressBar)lvAlbums[curAlbum].lvTracks[curTrack].spTrack["pb1"]

Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to reference the progressbar control, I simply bound data to it and updated the data:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="pb1" Value="{Binding XPath=@Progress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="5px" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="145"/>
```

Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works for you :

```
var innerListView = lvAlbums.ItemTemplate.FindName("lvTracks", lvAlbums) as ListView;
ProgressBar pbar = innerListView.ItemTemplate.FindName("pb1", innerListView ) as ProgressBar;
```

Comment: I already tried something like that. I get a template error: "This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied."

Comment: Also, this doesn't give me a specific occurrence of the progressbar. For instance, I have 3 albums with 10 tracks each and each track has its own progress bar. 

The user sees a list of albums and tracks and then -- for sake of argument -- hits the "Download" button. My code loops through the XML, gets the first album and first track and downloads it async. During the download, I want to update the appropriate progressbar associated with that ablum/track combo.